# PDO & Foreach (Illegal String Offset)

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

In my application, I'm attempting to return to each MySQL Row. Except, when I attempt to do so, I get the error :

> [Fri Oct 09 17:03:56.314003 2015] [:error] [pid 10641] [client 127.0.0.1:40897] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'Date' in /var/www/html/ViewTicket.php on line 79, referer: http://localhost/Support
>
> [Fri Oct 09 17:03:56.314041 2015] [:error] [pid 10641] [client 127.0.0.1:40897] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'Content' in /var/www/html/ViewTicket.php on line 84, referer: http://localhost/Support

Here is my coding :

```
<?php
$pageT = "View Ticket";
require_once("core/inc.php");

    $ID = strip_tags(htmlentities($_GET['ID']));

    $db = new DB();
    $Config = new Config;
    $User   = new User;
    $Organize = new Organize;

    $Ticket = $db->fetchRow(
        'SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE ID = :id',
        [':id' => $ID]
    );

    $TR = $db->fetchRow(
        'SELECT * FROM ticket_replies WHERE TID = :tid',
        [':tid' => $ID]
    );

    $Poster = $db->fetchRow(
        'SELECT * FROM users WHERE UID = :poster',
        [':poster' => $Ticket['Poster']]
    );

    $Replier = $db->fetchRow(
        'SELECT * FROM users WHERE UID = :poster',
        [':poster' => $TR['Poster']]
    );

    if($Ticket == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, but this is an unkown ticket.";
        require_once("modules/design/footer.ris.php");
        die();
    }

    /*
    if($User->Info('UID') !== $Ticket['Poster']) {
        if($User->Info('Rank') !== "Support" || $User->Info('Rank') !== "Admin" || $User->Info('Rank') !== "Admin") {
            echo "Nice try, this is not your ticket. ;(";
            require_once("modules/design/footer.ris.php");
            die();
        }
    }
    */


    echo '
                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-9">
                                <div class="panel panel-default m-t-20">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h3 class="panel-title">
                                        <span class="label label-warning"> '.strip_tags(htmlentities($Ticket['Priority'])).'</span> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                        <span class="label label-primary"> '.strip_tags(htmlentities($Ticket['Dept'])).'</span> '.strip_tags(htmlentities($Ticket['Title'])).''; if($User->Info('Rank') == "Admin" || $User->Info('Rank') == "Owner") { echo "<a style='float:right;margin-left:5px;'class='btn btn-icon waves-effect waves-light btn-danger m-b-5' href=''>Delete Ticket</a> <a style='float:right;margin-left:5px;'class='btn btn-icon waves-effect waves-light btn-info m-b-5' href=''>View Logs</a> &nbsp; <a style='float:right;' class='btn btn-icon waves-effect waves-light btn-info m-b-5' href='AP_EditUser?UID=".$Poster['UID']."'>Edit User</a> &nbsp;"; } echo '</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="media m-b-30">
                                            <div class="media-body"><span class="media-meta pull-right">'.strip_tags(htmlentities($Organize->timeElapsedFromUNIX($Ticket['Date']))).'</span>
                                                <h4 class="text-primary m-0"><u>'.strip_tags(htmlentities($Poster['Username'])).'</u></h4>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                            <p>
                                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; '.strip_tags(htmlentities($Ticket['Details'])).'
                                            </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                ';

                                    foreach ($TR as $Reply) {

                                    if($Replier['Rank'] == "Support" || $Replier['Rank'] == "Admin" || $Replier['Rank'] == "Owner") {

                                    echo '
                                <div style="border-top:4px solid red;" class="panel panel-default m-t-20">
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="media m-b-30">
                                            <div class="media-body"><span class="media-meta pull-right">'.strip_tags(htmlentities($Organize->timeElapsedFromUNIX($Reply['Date']))).'</span>
                                                <h4 class="text-primary m-0">'.strip_tags(htmlentities($Replier['Username'])).'</h4> <small>'.$Replier['Rank'].'</small>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                            <p>
                                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; '.$Organize->showBBcodes($Reply['Content']).'
                                            </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    ';

                                } else {
                                    echo '
                                <div style="border-top:4px solid #CCC;" class="panel panel-default m-t-20">
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="media m-b-30">
                                            <div class="media-body"><span class="media-meta pull-right">'.strip_tags(htmlentities($Organize->timeElapsedFromUNIX($TR['Date']))).'</span>
                                                <h4 class="text-primary m-0">'.strip_tags(htmlentities($Replier['Username'])).'</h4> <small>'.$Replier['Rank'].'</small>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                            <p>
                                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; '.strip_tags(htmlentities($Reply['Details'])).'
                                            </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    ';
                                }
                                break;
                            }

                                echo '
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="media">
                                            <form role="form" method="POST">
                                            <div class="media-body">
                                                <textarea class="wysihtml5 form-control" id="replyDetails" name="replyDetails" rows="9" placeholder="Reply here..."></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="text-right">
                                            <button type="submit" id="addReply" name="addReply" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light m-t-30 w-md">Send Reply</button>
                                        </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    ';

    if(isset($_POST['addReply'])) {
        $Details = strip_tags(htmlentities($_POST['replyDetails']));

        if(empty($Details)) {
            echo '<div class="col-md-8"><div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Could not send reply :</strong> <br />  &bullet; You forgot a field or two. Please try again.</div></div>';
        } elseif(strlen($Details) > 700) {
            echo '<div class="col-md-8"><div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Could not send reply :</strong> <br />  &bullet; You cannot exeed 700 characters. Please try again.</div></div>';

        } else {
            $Values = [
                'TID'             => $ID,
                'Poster'          => $User->Info('UID'),
                'Content'         => $Details,
                'Date'            => time()
            ];

            $insertValues = $db->insert('ticket_replies')->values($Values);

            $Values2 = [
                'Username'        => $User->Info('Username'),
                'UID'             => $User->Info('UID'),
                'IP'              => $Logs->IP(),
                'Platform'        => $Logs->Browser(),
                'Type'            => '8',
                'Value'           => 'Replied to a ticket.',
                'Date'            => $Logs->Date(),
            ];

            $insertValues2 = $db->insert('logs')->values($Values2);
        }
    }
```

To go along with the error above, it doesn't output any error just returns '1'.

Comment: I would probably say that `'SELECT * FROM ticket_replies WHERE TID = :tid',` this query is not returning any field called `Content`. please do `print_r($TR):exit;` and pass the result here.

Comment: Sorry for late response, I get
`array(5) { ["ID"]=> string(1) "1" ["TID"]=> string(1) "1" ["Poster"]=> string(1) "1" ["Content"]=> string(23) "Test content, kthx ily." ["Date"]=> string(10) "1444357123" }`

Comment: but that's just an element? is taht `print_r($TR)` or `print_r($Reply)`

Comment: That's `print_r($TR)` `$Reply` returns `string(1) "1"`

Comment: THats the problem because you're trying to get Content from reply `$Reply['Content']`

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to? I've done the same thing for viewing your tickets, and it works fine for that. Also when I try to do `$TR['Content']` it only fetches one of the rows.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it, thank you though. I changed the ticket query, and the foreach.

`

```
    $Reply = $db->fetchRows('SELECT * FROM ticket_replies WHERE TID = :tid', [':tid' => $ID]);
    foreach ($Reply as $TR) {
                                        $Replier = $db->fetchRow(
                                            'SELECT * FROM users WHERE UID = :poster',
                                            [':poster' => $TR['Poster']]
                                        );

`
```